# Laptop not powering on

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power, water-damage

Two days ago, I was hurrying to an exam and had to walk in the rain, resulting to my backpack getting rained on. When I got home, there was a tiny amount of water on the side of my laptop, but it didn't appear to had gotten inside, so after wiping off all the water I tried to power it on. It didn't. The little LED to indicate power didn't light up. There was absolutely no sign off power. I brought it to a small local laptop repair shop, and got it opened. THERE WAS ABSOLUTELY NO SIGN OF WATER or moisture. The guy there told me that I had to get my motherboard replaced. He used a multimeter and it seemed that the AC input was working correctly. A motherboard is expensive, and my laptop is just over a year old. I'm off tomorrow to get a second opinion, because I'm a CS student with projects due soon and I have to get this fixed but I'm also hesitant to spend that much cash if I'm not sure. Could it be the CMOS battery or some other thing I can check before I take the laptop to another technician? I'd really like to have some idea of what went wrong here because if it wasn't the water, could my i5 motherboard be really broken so early into my laptop's life?

Comment: There are a few things to check. Try removing the battery and power supply, then try booting without the battery. Also, check if there is power on the USB ports. Does someone you know have a laptop with a similar power supply? If so try your power supply on their laptop. And don't forget to check your warranty: many modern laptops are covered for two years. When you do sort out the problem, buy a protective case!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried them, but still nothing. My warranty was only for a year and expired this January.

Comment: I cannot think of any other simple checks. It seems an unlikely coincidence that the motherboard should fail at the same time as the laptop got wet, but remember that it was powered by the battery, even though it was not plugged into the mains and booted at the time. I guess you will have to accept what the experts say, but you are wise to get a second opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I realize to how little hope I have right now. But I'm still hoping against everything that there will be a cheaper and easier fix.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in your laptop, physical or electrical damage can cause a short circuit. A short circuit will consume all available power, causing your laptop to not turn on. If your power adapter LED comes on when you plug it into the wall, but then goes off when you plug in the laptop, you probably have a short circuit.

Try to pull the battery and unplug the laptop from the external power source. hold the power button down for 3-5 minutes. Plug everything back in to see if that works. if not, your laptop may have a reset button, you'd have to poke it with a pin